# Convert a non-digit string to a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, int

This is not your typical string to integer cast or conversion.

Is there an easy way I can get a numbered representation of a string in JavaScript? Imagine I want the word `Apple` in some sort of integer representation.

I know I can build a dictionary of all the letters of the alphabet and assign them numbers, then add up the letters for a given string, but I thought there might be an easier way.

PS. Capitalization doesn't matter in this case, but even if it is accounted for in the conversion, all is still good for my use case.

Comment: You can use `str.charCodeAt(index);` to get a character unicode value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will fit your needs but you can use [`String.prototype.charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method to get a character Unicode value:

```js
var str = "Apple",
    codes = [], i;

for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    codes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
}

alert("Apple: " + codes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript charCodeAt.  This will give you the char code at a specific index.  You can add the char code's together to get your number.

Ex.

```
var number = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
{
    number = number + string.charCodeAt(i);
}

//number will have your number
```